# JS create new child TR with two TD bits of information

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem - I am having difficulty creating the new TR row dynamically and then getting it to insert the data as a new table (TD) line.

The full question is as below;

Create a script that inserts a new row with the values March and £580 as the last child of the following HTML table.

```
<table id=”takings”>
    <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>£100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>£300</td>
    </tr>

// insert here

</table>
```

My attempt or idea was to create the TR first and then for each item in the text array add a TD within that newly created TR. However this doesn't seem to create anything.

My JS is as below;

```
function insertNode(newNodeTypeTD, newNodeTypeTR, newNodeTextArray, element) {
    let parentElement = document.getElementById(element);
    let newTR = document.createElement(newNodeTypeTR);

    for (let i = 0; newNodeTextArray.length; i++) {
        let newText = document.createTextNode(newNodeTextArray);
        newTR.appendChild(newText);
        parentElement.insertBefore(newTR, parentElement.children[i]);
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    insertNode("td", "tr", ["March", "£580"], "takings")
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Where are you stuck with this, exactly? I don't see any JS here. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is not a code writing service. We expect you to make your best attempt at solving the problem, and showing us the code you've written.

Answer (score 0):

Note this line: `for (let i = 0; newNodeTextArray.length; i++) {`

`newNodeTextArray.length` is 1 or greater, so this condition always returns `true`.

What you likely meant to do was

`for (let i = 0; i < newNodeTextArray.length; i++) {`